# How to use regex in the AWS S3 Lifecycle Expiration Prefix Rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, amazon-glacier

s3 bucket with "folders" 5.10, 5.11, 5.12, 5.13. I would like to create a rule using regex like /*/5.1[1-3]/ to archive folder 5.11, 5.12 and 5.13.

can anyone suggest how can I achieve this using terraform.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly its not possible. S3 lifecycles rules **do not support** regular expressions.

You have to explicitly different rules for different prefixes.